# Clickonce deployment equivalent for Dotnet core applications

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-core, clickonce

We have a dotnet core console application which we want to use ClickOnce deployment. Mainly every time the user runs the application, it should check for update and update itself.

This was available by default with ClickOnce deployment in dotnetframework applications. Dotnet core provides Framework Dependent Deployment &  Self Contained Deployment. But in both the case, updates have to manually pushed.

Please suggest how we can achieve ClickOnce deployment for dotnet core applications and if there is any tool available in the market to achieve the same.

Comment: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Comment: As a kind of official Microsoft statement. Scott Hunter suggets to use MSIX in his blog's  (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/ - scroll down to the comments section)

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: no @Shemiroth, that project got dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but maybe useful in the future:

I think you just need to wait till NET 5:
Latest announcement includes ClickOnce

https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/9
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-2/
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently available today

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2022

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, you can use the Publish tool to publish .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5, or newer, Windows Desktop applications using ClickOnce from Visual Studio.

To get started follow these steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose Publish (or use the Build > Publish menu item).
2. In the Publish wizard, select Folder.
3. In the Specific target page, select ClickOnce.

And the relevant parts to updates:

> If you selected to install from a UNC path or web site, this page allows you to specify whether the application is available offline. When selected, this option will list the application on the users Start Menu and it allows the application to be automatically updated when a new version is published. By default, updates are available from the Install location. If you wish to have a different location for updates, you can specify that using the Update Settings link. If you do not want the application to be available offline, it will run from the install location