# Is "Click Once" supported for .Net Core WPF?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, clickonce, migrating

What is the correct pattern/ what packages to use for WPF click once deployment in .net core 3.0( earlier versions are okay too)?

I am currently migrating a WPF app from netframework 4.8 to .net core 3.0. I have been using click once deployment in in the previous version. I was using System.Deployment package which is not supported in .net core. Is there any substitution for the package and what is the correct way to implement click once deployment in .net core and is it even possible? Should it be done using MSIX, if so is there any good guide about MSIX click once deployment?

Comment: you should use MSIX according to a blog Post by Microsofts Scott Hunter referenced here in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899472/clickonce-deployment-equivalent-for-dotnet-core-applications

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. After digging up about MSIX i found this guide [link](https://montemagno.com/distributing-a-net-core-3-wpf-and-winforms-app-with-msix/?source=post_page-----34b2489befce----------------------) i have few questions: 
1) so as i understand, there wont be any code inside visual studio for click once updates, they will be automatically done in the background, when i publish a new version? 
2) The guid doesn't really include any direct usage of MSIX, so is the MSIX being used with the UWP? @Jan

Comment: Sorry, i have not used it myself, yet due to limitations at my employer.  We re not yet in win 10 1903, which would allow for another method of publishing if I remember correctly. At the moment it is just publishing to a network folder for me :(

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to deploy your app?

Comment: I am no longer working on that project, so i can't comment. As far as i know, the plan was to try using the old libraries and see if it will cause any errors or not. I've spent 4 days researching and i didn't find anything useful, that i could replace "click once" with, this is still a problem without a solution

Answer (score 1):

Support for ClickOnce is now available in .NET Core 3.1 and higher (you need Visual Studio 2019).

Source [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2022):

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, you can use the **Publish** tool to publish .NET Core 3.1, or newer, Windows Desktop applications using ClickOnce from Visual Studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30480422)